# Tensor products isomorphic to hom-sets with a structure

Tags: tensor-products, exceptional-isomorphisms

In which cases the tensor product of objects, say A and B, is (isomorphic with) the objects with the carrier set Hom(A,B) and a corresponding structure?

Comment: What objects?  What corresponding structure?  What kind of isomorphism?

Comment: 1. What objets? - that is exactly, what I want to know. I know it is the case e.g. for vector spaces, but what about for example graphs (directed)?

Comment: 2. What corresponding structure? Perhaps I should write "in which concrete categories"

Comment: What kind of isomorphism? The "standard" isomorphism, that means a morphism having an inverse morphism.

Comment: That's the definition of an isomorphism.  Generally, one either a) asks a much more concrete question, where it is very specific in what category these various objects are to be interpreted, or b) asks about the conditions under which a certain natural morphism can be an isomorphism.  Usually, questions of the second form have much more interesting answers, while questions of the first form are potentially very tiresome without motivation, or at least clear bounds on the problem.

Comment: For example, I can easily point out that there is such an isomorphism when $A=0$ or $B=0$—or I could, if you had specified that our category has a zero object.  Of course, this is rather boring, and it's unclear how many such examples would suffice to answer the question, if any would.

Comment: It's also unclear what you think a tensor product _is_, or a Hom-set for that matter.  As functors, these had better at least be representable objects, which is definitely not the case in every concrete category.

Comment: OK, I modify my question. In which concrete categories the tensor product of objects A and B is (isomorphic to) the Hom-set Hom(A,B)? By the tensor product of A and B I mean any objects C and a bimorphism t from the (cartesian) product A and B in C such that forany bimorphism from f : A X b -> D there exista exactly one morphism f# : C -> D such that f = tf#. In other words this tensor product is the initial object in the category of bimorphisms on A X B.

Comment: First of all, you're trying to compare objects of your concrete category (tensor products) with sets (hom-sets).  In what manner?  Do you have some expectation that the hom-set be endowed with a structure that is in some way compatible with these "bimorphisms"?  If we allow the structure to be arbitrary, then this is simply a question about cardinality.

Comment: But I really don't know your meaning of "bimorphism", and I'm not sure that there is really such a categorical notion... not as such, anyway.  I don't know how graphs factor in, but the tensor product can be very different in different categories... the graph-theoretic one is a product, but the tensor product of commutative rings is a coproduct, so we are still left with wildly different types of categorical behavior for tensor products, even if there is a definition that works.

Comment: By the way... it seems that the tensor product of graphs can be interpreted as the tensor product of adjacency matrices, so you can look at both examples as linear algebra if you so desire.

Comment: Thank You for Your patience. Well, lets repeat the problem. The question is "In which concrete categories the tensor product - of objects A and B  is (isomorphic - not necessarily naturally - to) the hom-set Hom(A,B) endowed in the corresponding (i.e. of the category C) structure?“

Comment: By the tensor product of objects A and B in a category C we mean the bimorphism t :AxB->D (i.e. a function being a morphism of  C in any of both variables separately) such that for any bimorrphism f:AxB_>F  there exist exactly one morphism f# of C with f=tf#.

Comment: We assume, of course, C is cartesian, i.e alll needed (co)products and and initial objects exist. This is the case in the category Vect, of linear spaces. I don't thint in the category of graphs we can go simply via adjacency matrices.

Comment: Perhaps this is the case when we consider graphs with at most one arrow between nodes. In a more general case it seems to be similar to (underlying graph of) the tensor product of categories. Thank You for Your valuable comments and please help me in this problem.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand this construction.  Let's start from the beginning: Can you give an example of the kind of isomorphism that you are looking for?  If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, then are you just interested in the fact that $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V,W)$ has the same dimension as $V\otimes_k W$, or do you have some correspondence between the two spaces in mind?  Probably I can figure something out from there; I guess that the category of graphs you have in mind can be interpreted as some kind of module category.

Comment: And I would think that even for directed multigraphs, you can still write down the adjacency matrix, it just won't be symmetric, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's my attempt.

If $R$ is a principal ideal domain, $M$ and $N$ finitely-generated $R$-modules, then we can decompose $M$ and $N$ into direct sums $M=\oplus_k R/{I_k}$ and $N = \oplus_l R/{J_l}$.

We have $R/I \otimes R/J = R/(I+J)$, but $\operatorname{Hom}(R/I, R/J) = (J:I)/(I+J)$.  So there is a natural (for cyclic modules only!) inclusion $\operatorname{Hom}(R/I, R/J) \to R/I \otimes R/J$, which is surjective if and only if $(J:I) = R$, i.e. $I\subset J$.

In particular, $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic whenever $I_k \subset J_l$ *for all $k$ and all $l$*.  In some sense, we have this property when $M$ is "more free" than $N$, e.g. $M=\mathbb{Z}/6$, $N=\mathbb{Z}/2$.

So at the very least, we have a natural-ish (depends on the decomposition) isomorphism $M \otimes N \to \operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$ whenever $M$ is free, and $N$ is finitely generated.

---

The above applies to vector spaces, *and* to vector space endomorphisms, which are $k[T]$-modules.  In the latter, something like the following is the case: endomorphisms $T,T'$ should have a natural-ish isomorphism $T \otimes T' \to \operatorname{Hom}(T,T')$ whenever the characteristic polynomial of $T'$ divides the minimal polynomial of $T$.

This should shed some light on the case of graphs, which can be thought of as endomorphisms, even for directed multigraphs (send a basis vector $v_e$ to the sum of $v_{e'}$ over outgoing arrows $e\to e'$).  I believe that the tensor product is the same, in which case it should be enough to look at minimal and characteristic polynomials of the adjacency matrices.  If we restrict to connected graphs then I think the modules are cyclic, and we can even make this natural.

Comment: Thanks, I know the case of modules and - better known - vector spaces. My question was "Are these cases the only known cases?"

Comment: @vald The only known cases of _what_?  You still haven't said what category you want to compare these two functors in.  I just wrote down an easy-to-compute case that covers the two examples you were interested in; if you want some more technical result, then _ask for something specific_.  Of course there are lots of ways that these functors could be isomorphic-as-somethings (as written, they're just _sets_!), but without some kind of module structure, I think you'll have a hard time writing down something meaningful.

Comment: @vald But there are already obvious generalizations to other categories of modules, and while we're at it, let's throw in group and monoid actions.  Let's define something all universal-algebry about something acting on something else, and write down a lot of theorems there.  The sky is the limit, but you have to have _something that you want to look for_.

Comment: @vald And no, your question _did not ask_ "are these the only known cases", in fact, your question includes no cases whatsoever.

Comment: To be more precise. The "standard" categorical definition of tensor product of objects A and B in a given cartesian category, say C, defines it as a pair (t, T) with t : AxB->T being a bimorphism of C with the property that for any bimorphism f : AxB->D there exists exactly one morphism f# : T->D such that f=tf#. In other words any bimorphism from the (cartesian) product AxB factorises by t. The "usual" constructions of such a tensor products in categories of abelian groups, moduls or vector spaces go via some coproducts. I would like to know tensor product constructions in other categories.

Comment: @vald Then make a question about that.  This question is about some relationship with Hom that you have so far refused to specify.